# Unexpected NullPointerException()

Tags: java, javafx

just getting familiar with java - i am confused a bit here, i had a simple controller with the following code

```
package com.ajaxict.edhub;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class WelcomeController {

    public Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private Parent root;

    public void switchToWelcome(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("welcome_view.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("EdHub - Welcome");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void switchToRegister(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("register_view.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("EdHub - Register");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public void quit_frame (ActionEvent event) {
    // stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
      stage.close(); 
    }

}
```

From the code above i believe the stage property is initialised whenever i call the switchToWelcome() or switchToRegister() method - so that if i later call the quit_frame() method there won't be any issue since this stage property is very accessible through out this class. but i still get a NullPointerException each time i try to call the quit_frame() method

i added the now commented line in the quit_frame() method is re-initialise the stage before calling close() method upon it and things work fine. but i feel i don't need this line, since the stage is already initialised with the switchToRegister() i called initially.

Here is the last parts of the bulk error message

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.stage.Stage.close()" because "this.stage" is null
at com.ajaxict.edhub/com.ajaxict.edhub.WelcomeController.quit_app(WelcomeController.java:45)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
... 53 more
```

i tried to re-initialise the stage property again within the quit_frame() method, and it works but i don't think will be the best idea

---

A Reproducible Example below: WelcomeMain.java

```
package com.ajaxict.edhub;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WelcomeMain extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(WelcomeMain.class.getResource("welcomeView.fxml"));
    //  Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
        stage.setTitle("EdHub - Welcome");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

my welcomeView.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="309.0" prefWidth="543.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.ajaxict.edhub.WelcomeController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="txt_email" layoutX="241.0" layoutY="147.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="263.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="txt_pword" layoutX="241.0" layoutY="192.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="263.0" />
      <Button fx:id="btn_login" layoutX="426.0" layoutY="258.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="78.0" text="Log In" />
      <Label layoutX="45.0" layoutY="147.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="141.0" text="Email Address">
         <font>
            <Font size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="45.0" layoutY="182.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="Password">
         <font>
            <Font size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="23.0" layoutY="22.0" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="499.0" text="EdHub ">
         <font>
            <Font name="Monotype Corsiva" size="52.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="btn_register" layoutX="138.0" layoutY="258.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchToRegister" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="78.0" text="Register" />
      <Button fx:id="btn_quit" layoutX="45.0" layoutY="258.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#quit_app" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="78.0" text="Quit" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

my registerView.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="487.0" prefWidth="564.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.ajaxict.edhub.WelcomeController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="txt_email" layoutX="248.0" layoutY="205.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="263.0" />
      <Button fx:id="btn_login" layoutX="142.0" layoutY="420.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchToWelcome" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="78.0" text="Log In" />
      <Label layoutX="52.0" layoutY="205.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="141.0" text="Lastname">
         <font>
            <Font size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="50.0" layoutY="338.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="Password">
         <font>
            <Font size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="33.0" layoutY="19.0" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="499.0" text="EdHub ">
         <font>
            <Font name="Monotype Corsiva" size="52.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="btn_register" layoutX="433.0" layoutY="420.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="78.0" text="Register" />
      <Button fx:id="btn_quit" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="420.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#quit_app" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="78.0" text="Quit" />
      <Label layoutX="52.0" layoutY="292.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="Gender">
         <font>
            <Font size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ComboBox layoutX="247.0" layoutY="297.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="263.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="txt_email1" layoutX="248.0" layoutY="250.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="263.0" />
      <Label layoutX="52.0" layoutY="250.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="141.0" text="Email Address">
         <font>
            <Font size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="txt_email2" layoutX="251.0" layoutY="160.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="263.0" />
      <Label layoutX="55.0" layoutY="160.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="141.0" text="Firstname">
         <font>
            <Font size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <PasswordField layoutX="245.0" layoutY="343.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="263.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

my welcomeController.java

```
package com.ajaxict.edhub;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WelcomeController {

    public Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private Parent root;


    public void switchToWelcome(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("welcomeView.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("EdHub - Welcome");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void switchToRegister(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("registerView.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("EdHub - Register");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public void quit_app (ActionEvent event) {
//   stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        this.stage.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have only one instance of WelcomeController ? BTW, stage should be private as well instead of public and if you need to reach it outside of your WelcomeController class then create a proper method.

Comment: Oh, the stage property was initally private - i had no intention of making it public from the start, but i think it is part of what i had changed unknowingly while trying to figure out the cause of the NullPointerException

Comment: If your code throws a `NullPointerException`, you should take a close look at the message. Since Java 14 Oracle enhanced the NPE to show more detailed information about the cause. If this does not help, you should definitely add the NPE to your question.

Comment: Also, i was able to call the two switch methods without issues, but the quit_frame() would throw the NullPointerException

Comment: Please create and post a [mre]. Since you have multiple FXML files, you would need to post all the FXML files as well as all the controllers: so please make the smallest example that shows the problem before posting it here.

Comment: That said, what is wrong with injecting the root node from the FXML, and then just doing `root.getScene().getWindow().hide()`?

Comment: when writing the [mcve] please fix the java naming violations (no underscores)

Comment: my question has been updated to include a minimal reproducible example - which include just 4 files - the main, controller and the 2 fxml views

Comment: good - but you forgot to fix the naming violation

Answer (score 3):

The instance variable `stage` is only initialized in each controller when you call either `switchToWelcome` or `switchToRegister`. But in both cases, you then immediately replace the current view with one loaded from an FXML file, which will create a new controller. The `stage` variable will not have been initialized in that new controller instance. Consequently, any time `quitApp()` is invoked, `stage` is null on the instance on which it is invoked.

It is a bad idea to use the same controller class for controllers created for different FXML files, because it leads directly to the kind of confusion that is causing this error. Each FXML file should have its own controller class.

To get a reference to the current window, it's much cleaner to just get it from a node displayed in that window, which can be injected into the controller in the usual way.

So for example you can do

```
@FXML
private Parent root ;
```

and then

```
@FXML
private void quitApp() {
    root.getScene().getWindow().hide();
}
```

which will close the current window. If you literally want to close the entire application (not just close the current window, which may or may not exit the application), you can of course do `Platform.exit()` instead.

Here is a version of your application using this approach.

Note the addition of the `fx:id` to the root elements of the FMXL.

WelcomeView.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="root" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="309.0" prefWidth="543.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.ajaxict.edhub.WelcomeController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="txtEmail" layoutX="241.0" layoutY="147.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="263.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="txtPword" layoutX="241.0" layoutY="192.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="263.0" />
      <Button fx:id="btnLogin" layoutX="426.0" layoutY="258.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="78.0" text="Log In" />
      <Label layoutX="45.0" layoutY="147.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="141.0" text="Email Address">
         <font>
            <Font size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="45.0" layoutY="182.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="Password">
         <font>
            <Font size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="23.0" layoutY="22.0" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="499.0" text="EdHub ">
         <font>
            <Font name="Monotype Corsiva" size="52.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="btnRegister" layoutX="138.0" layoutY="258.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchToRegister" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="78.0" text="Register" />
      <Button fx:id="btnQuit" layoutX="45.0" layoutY="258.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#quitApp" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="78.0" text="Quit" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

WelcomeController.java:

```
package com.ajaxict.edhub;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WelcomeController {

    @FXML
    private Parent root;


    public void switchToWelcome() throws IOException {
        Parent newRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("welcomeView.fxml"));
        this.root.getScene().setRoot(newRoot);
    }

    public void switchToRegister() throws IOException {
        Parent newRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("registerView.fxml"));
        this.root.getScene().setRoot(newRoot);
    }


    public void quitApp() {
        this.root.getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }

}
```

(I don't really understand why your "Welcome" screen has "switch to welcome" functionality, but I left it in.)

registerView.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="root" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="487.0" prefWidth="564.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.ajaxict.edhub.RegisterController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="txtEmail" layoutX="248.0" layoutY="205.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="263.0" />
      <Button fx:id="btnLogin" layoutX="142.0" layoutY="420.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchToWelcome" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="78.0" text="Log In" />
      <Label layoutX="52.0" layoutY="205.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="141.0" text="Lastname">
         <font>
            <Font size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="50.0" layoutY="338.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="Password">
         <font>
            <Font size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="33.0" layoutY="19.0" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="499.0" text="EdHub ">
         <font>
            <Font name="Monotype Corsiva" size="52.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="btnRegister" layoutX="433.0" layoutY="420.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="78.0" text="Register" />
      <Button fx:id="btnQuit" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="420.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#quitApp" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="78.0" text="Quit" />
      <Label layoutX="52.0" layoutY="292.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="Gender">
         <font>
            <Font size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ComboBox layoutX="247.0" layoutY="297.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="263.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="txtEmail1" layoutX="248.0" layoutY="250.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="263.0" />
      <Label layoutX="52.0" layoutY="250.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="141.0" text="Email Address">
         <font>
            <Font size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="txtEmail2" layoutX="251.0" layoutY="160.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="263.0" />
      <Label layoutX="55.0" layoutY="160.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="141.0" text="Firstname">
         <font>
            <Font size="17.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <PasswordField layoutX="245.0" layoutY="343.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="263.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

RegisterController.java:

```
package com.ajaxict.edhub;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RegisterController {

    @FXML
    private Parent root;


    public void switchToWelcome() throws IOException {
        Parent newRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("welcomeView.fxml"));
        this.root.getScene().setRoot(newRoot);
    }

    


    public void quitApp () {
        this.root.getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }

}
```

You can obviously remove the duplicated code in the controllers by using delegation or inheritance.

Comment: This is the error i am getting when i re-wrote my code as you directed above:

```Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Scene.setRoot(javafx.scene.Parent)" because the return value of "javafx.scene.Parent.getScene()" is null
 at com.ajaxict.edhub/com.ajaxict.edhub.RegisterController.switchToWelcome(RegisterController.java:22)
```  

it is obviously complaining about the root which has not being initialised but we are attempting to call .getScene().setRoot() upon it

Comment: @Yusuf That should not be possible; make sure you are trying the latest version (I had some typos in the original).